# Shared Folder Between Azure VMs with Failover

Tags: azure

I have 2 Azure VMs I am using that will be responsible for hosting my website. I have traffic manager setup so that VM1 will run my website, and VM2 will be a failover.

I have the site setup working perfectly, except that my site allows users to upload images. These images simply are saved to the file system under the website (site.com/images/user2.jpg)

My question is how to keep these images in sync. For instance, if VM1 is up and a user uploads an image, that will be stored on VM1. If VM1 goes down, VM2 fires off, and the site is back up and running perfectly. Except, it does not have the image that the user uploaded when VM1 was up.

I've looked into [Azure file storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/), but that appears to need some code changes, which simply can't be done at this time. Is there any other way to keep the two failover systems in sync? It seems like failover isn't a good approach if not.

Comment: This is an opinion-soliciting (and broad) question, as there are multiple ways to accomplish this. Natively, Azure has File Service (SMB) and blob storage, for durable storage, along with several database services. If you're choosing to store files locally on individual VM's, you'd have to come up with your own sync mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve it is using Azure File storage service.

File storage is a shared storage for applications using SMB 2.1 or 3.0 protocol.

Azure virtual machines  can share file data across application components via mounted shares.

You'll need no issue some powershell commands to setup the File Share, and after that you should use `net use`  batch command to map the file share to a mounted unit on each virtual machine Then applications can access that mounted storage any other storage device.

Here you can find detailed information and video about how to implement that solution

### [How to use Azure File storage with Windows](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/#_mount-the-file-share)